# Is it possible to set some types generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I mean this for generic function or class:

```
function do<T>(data: T) {

}

function do<Imake | ITomake>(data: Imake | ITomake) {

}
```

In my case I have class:

```
class A {
   public data: T;
}
```

Where variable `data` can take `T` type, but T can be `Imake | ITomake` or others interface types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You can make your class Generic. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

```
class A<T> {
   public data: T;
}
```